# RavenDB Studio Management Showing 0 Documents

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I've just started playing about with RavenDB and I am able to add, delete and query for documents from the database. However when i view the database studio on localhost:8080 it shows the database as having 0 documents. Does anyone have any idea why this might be ?

Comment: Just to be sure, when you have this at the end of your link: **/raven/studio.html#/databases** , do you see more than one database?  If you see only one database and double click it, does it have any content?

Comment: Only one database with no content in it, yet i can use the data in the application.

Comment: figured it out i was saving into the system database

Comment: @DavidClapperton: Can you post this answer and mark it as complete? You'll get a Self-Learner badge for it ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner

Answer (score 0):

Change the connection string to contain the database name

```
<add name="RavenDB" connectionString="Url=http://localhost:8080;Database=MyDatabaseName" />
```